# What is an equivalent Portuguese expression for "actions speak louder than words"?

Tags: expressões, tradução

What is an equivalent Portuguese expression for the phrase "actions speak louder than words"? ([reference](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/actions_speak_louder_than_words)) This phrase is often used to in relation to someone's unfulfilled promises.

Example 1:

- A: *I'll come tonight.*
- B: *You said that last night, and the night before.  Actions speak louder than words.*

Example 2: *He has many great ideas, but what good are they?  Actions speak louder than words.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good portuguese version is:

> Palavras, leva-as o vento.

I see it mostly used with the meaning of "words are forgotten; if you mean that, do something about it".

Comment: Ah, this is similar to the Spanish expression: *Las palabras se las lleva el viento*.  Is this more common to say than the more literal translations?

Comment: Yes, it's more idiomatic than the more literal translation.

Answer (score 8):

You can have multiple variants for that expression, but I believe the word *atos* instead of *ações* is more commonly used:

> - actions **worth** more than words: *[atos **valem** mais que palavras](http://quemdisse.com.br/frase.asp?frase=43853)* (it seems this expression is already regarded as a
>     Portuguese proverb);
> - actions **weight** more than words: *atos **pesam** mais que palavras*;
> - actions **are more significant/remarkable** than words: *atos **são mais significantes/notáveis** que palavras*;
> - actions **are preferable** to words: *atos **são preferíveis** a palavras*
> - actions **speak louder** than words: [*atos **falam mais alto** que palavras*](http://quemdisse.com.br/frase.asp?frase=91700)
> - attitudes **speak more** than words: [*atitudes **falam mais** que palavras*](http://pensador.uol.com.br/atitudes_falam_mais_que_as_palavras/25/)

None of these are wrong grammatically, but the most commonly used in Portuguese seems to be the one associated to the **worth** of actions. The definite articles *os* and *as* can be omitted in any of these expressions (as in English).

Comment: I quite like *atos falam mais alto que palavras.* Vou passar a usar.

Answer (score 6):

In terms of popular expressions, there's one (Brazilian portuguese) that can be used with the opposite meaning, which is **Falar da boca pra fora**. It means something like **Speak from the mouth out**. As you can imagine, it's only applicable in situation involving what the person says, so only example #1. It could be translated/adapted as:

- A: *Eu irei esta noite.*
- B: *Você falou a mesma coisa na noite passada, e na anterior. Você só fala da boca pra fora.*

Because of the different construction, the text has to be adapted. Still, I think this is closer to what you would hear in Brazil. Precisely, the expression means that despite saying something, the person doesn't truly believe/mean it and/or plan to do it.

Answer (score 5):

A equivalent expression is *As ações valem mais que as palavras*, although I don't think it to be very common to say this.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

> ## Entre falar e fazer, há muito que fazer
>
> > saying dedicated to all good talkers whose verbal capacity is inversely proportional to their skill to execute what they say
> >
> > *provérbio esse dedicado a todos os bem-falantes cuja capacidade para o verbo é inversamente proporcional às competências para executar aquilo que dizem*
> >     <sub>[vozesdarua.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/do-falar-ao-fazer](https://vozesdarua.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/do-falar-ao-fazer/)</sub>

The attribution I found around is "traditional saying".